# Average end point of 1-dimensional random walk?

Tags: random-walk

Is it possible to estimate the average end point of a 1-dimensional random walk of n steps where the probability of going "left" is p and going "right" is 1-p?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes: the mean of the endpoint is exactly $(1-2p)n$, the endpoint itself is $(1-2p)n+O(\sqrt{n})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_t$ be the position at time $t$.

We can think of the random walk as being the sum of a set of random variables, $Z_1$, $Z_2$, $Z_3$, ..., each taking the value 1 with probability $p$ and the value -1 with probability $1-p$.

Hence:

$$X_t = \sum\limits_{i=1}^t Z_i$$

So by the linearity of expectation:

$$\mathbb{E}[X_t] = \sum\limits_{i=1}^t\mathbb{E}[Z_i] = \sum\limits_{i=1}^tp -(1-p) = (2p - 1)t$$

Comment: I was thinking about applying this to estimating the average bankroll after t games of playing a game where we have probability p of winning (1-p) of losing. If we win we gain 1-2*r units where r is a game fee that is typically very small comparing to 1, (for example 2% of 1 unit).  If we lose a game we lose 1 unit. In this case the expectation would be ((1-2r)p-(1-p))t.